# StateWide Collated Public county data set

Tags: county

Is there a easier way to download public data from county government website ( property sales) other than individually from each county?(USA) Is there a collated data set state wise that is available for download?

Answer (score -1):

Typically no, your best route would be to contact NSGIC for each states GIS Coordinator who may be able to point you to efforts to aggregate and standardize core datasets.